# C#.NET PDF DLL - Cannot create activex component

Tags: dll, com, activex, components

I have recently written a simple C#.NET Dll to handle the opening and printing of PDFs. My work uses an ERP system that tries to call Oracle AutoVue (AutoVue.Application) via COM. My dll is to be registered in place of AutoVue and provide better integration with the ERP system.

We have six workstations that need the DLL to be deployed on, one being my development machine. Attempts at using Regasm.exe have proven fruitless (same exception,) but when I manually add the registry entries, it seems to work fine on three of the six workstations. A couple of months ago I was able to get this workstation working the same as the others. When I went to update the DLL I found that the workstation had the exception.

The six workstations are working (or not) as follows:
One: Development, working
Three: Entries manually added, working
One: Entries manually added, non-working
One: Not touched, TBD

The ERP app doesn't throw an exception, calling via the following VB.NET app throws a "Cannot create activex component" exception.

```
Dim Obj As Object
Sub Main()
    Obj = CreateObject("AutoVue.Application")

    'PRINT
    'Obj.Execute("WINDOW SHOW")
    'Obj.Execute("CHILD SHOW")
    'Obj.Execute("FILE OPEN ""S:\****\****\****\****.PDF""")
    'Obj.Execute("PAUSE 2000")
    'Obj.Execute("PRINT")
    'Obj.Execute("CHILD CLOSE")

    'OPEN
    Obj.Execute("Child NEW")
    Obj.Execute("FILE OPEN ""S:\****\****\****\****.PDF""")
    Obj.Execute("WINDOW CASCADE")
    Obj.Execute("WINDOW SHOW")
    Obj.Execute("Child SHOW")
    ''MsgBox("work?", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End Sub
```

Below are the registry entries that have worked on the three other workstations.
Using HKCU Has yielded the same results on the offending workstation.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoVue.Application]
@="AutoVue.Application"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoVue.Application\CLSID]
@="{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}]
@="AutoVue.Application"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}\InprocServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="AutoVue.Application"
"Assembly"="JobBOSS Printing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=88cbab76fd6d8db7"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Install/JobBOSS Printing DLL/JobBOSS Printing.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="AutoVue.Application"
"Assembly"="JobBOSS Printing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=88cbab76fd6d8db7"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/Install/JobBOSS Printing DLL/JobBOSS Printing.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}\ProgId]
@="AutoVue.Application"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-    4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]
```

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to record the failing application looking through the registry.  Compare to the same recording on a machine that doesn't fail.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that I had missed one of the entries, it is working now. I find it odd that the only two calls to an existing entry have a result of "BUFFER TOO SMALL" and "BUFFER OVERFLOW":  HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}  HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{63A20B20-2357-101D-909B-0000C02E4A4A}\InprocServer32\2.0.0.0\Assembly  Any thoughts?